# I cannot call a function from another function because it is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I am calling one function from another function but it is "undefined".
What cause this problem in TypeScript?

```
export class CariComponent implements OnInit {

  satisSorumlusuId: number;

constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  setCellValue (newData, value, currentRowData) {
    console.log(this.getSatisSorumlusuId); // it prints undefined. So I cannot call this function here.
  }

  getSatisSorumlusuId(): number {
    return this.satisSorumlusuId;
  };

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

UPDATE
`setCellValue (newData, value, currentRowData)` function is DevExtreme function which I am using as third party product. This is how I set setCellValue.

```
<dxi-column 
        dataField="satisSorumlusu_Idstr"
        caption="satisSorumlusu_Idstr"
        [setCellValue]="setCellValue" >  
        <dxo-lookup 
            [dataSource]="satisSorumlusuDataSource"
            valueExpr="id"
            displayExpr="ismi">
    </dxo-lookup>       
</dxi-column>
```

If I make `console.log(this)`in setCellValue function, it contains only DevExtreme related properties ( You can see at the bottom  ). I mean there is no way to hook `getSatisSorumlusuId()` if you go with `this`. But how about that? What is the way to access properties and methods of Component ts file where actually everything is happening within it.

```
headerId: "dx-col-7"
visible: true
showInColumnChooser: true
allowFixing: false
allowReordering: false
autoExpandGroup: true
allowCollapsing: true
allowGrouping: false
allowFiltering: true
allowHiding: true
allowSorting: true
allowEditing: true
encodeHtml: true
trueText: "true"
falseText: "false"
allowExporting: true
caption: "satisSorumlusu_Idstr"
calculateCellValue: ƒ (data, skipDeserialization)
setCellValue: ƒ setCellValue(newData, value, currentRowData)
parseValue: ƒ (text)
calculateFilterExpression: ƒ ()
createFilterExpression: ƒ (filterValue)
lookup: {dataSource: inheritor, displayExpr: "ismi", calculateCellValue: ƒ, updateValueMap: ƒ, update: ƒ, …}
resizedCallbacks: Callback {_options: {…}, _list: Array(0), _queue: Array(0), _firing: false, _fired: false, …}
defaultCalculateCellValue: ƒ (data, skipDeserialization)
defaultSetCellValue: ƒ (data, value)
defaultParseValue: ƒ (text)
defaultCalculateFilterExpression: ƒ ()
defaultCreateFilterExpression: ƒ (filterValue)
dataField: "satisSorumlusu_Idstr"
selector: ƒ (data)
filterOperations: []
visibleIndex: 2
dataType: "string"
index: 2
alignment: "left"
defaultFilterOperations: []
defaultFilterOperation: "="
showEditorAlways: false
bestFitWidth: 177
```

Comment: Does `console.log(this.getSatisSorumlusuId());` work? Added parentheses.

Comment: Can we see how you call `setCellValue`?

Comment: The function is working as expected.  It is returning the value of the variable _satisSorumlusuId_ which is undefined.

Comment: change your variable declaration to _satisSorumlusuId: number = 10;_ and you will see that _10_ is the output.

Comment: @EJK - He does not call `getSatisSorumlusuId`. He should see the method definition in the console, not `undefined`. But it depends on how `setCellValue` is called.

Comment: @ConnorsFan - you are correct.  I did not look closely enough.  I thought it was a method call, but missed that it was lacking "()".

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. @ConnorsFan you are right, it is expected to print function definition but it doesnt. I have updated my post above please have a look.

Comment: One solution to your problem is to define `setCellValue` as an arrow function: `setCellValue = (newData, value, currentRowData) => { ... }`. See the duplicate reference for more details.

Comment: Arrow function made the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
export class CariComponent implements OnInit {

  satisSorumlusuId: number;

constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  setCellValue (newData, value, currentRowData) {
    console.log(this.getSatisSorumlusuId()); 
  }

  getSatisSorumlusuId(): number {
    return this.satisSorumlusuId;
  };

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

getSatisSorumlusuId() is a function that returns a number, so you should be calling it like **this.getSatisSorumlusuId();**.

For the variable **satisSorumlusuId** assigned with undefined initially, until you redefine **satisSorumlusuId** in the constructor or ngOnInit you will be getting undefined only.